# One-way ANOVA using weighted survey data in R

Tags: r, sampling, anova, survey

I have some survey data with sample weights, and I'm using the [survey](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survey/survey.pdf) package in R to compare means between demographic groups. I've had no problems using `svyttest` for two-sample t-tests involving dichotomous independent variables (e.g., sex).

However, I'm having some issues with the `anova.svglym` function in the survey package. When the generalized linear model has two independent variables, it works fine. But when the GLM has only one polytomous independent variable, I get a NULL result.

Here's some example code comparing BMI to demographics to describe my problem

```
library(survey)

# Survey design
healthdsgn = svydesign(data = healthsvy, id = ~SVYPSU, strata = ~SVYSTRATA, weights = ~SVYWT, nest = TRUE)

# This has two independent variables
# Outputs a normal ANOVA table
race_sex_glm = svyglm(BMI~RACE+SEX, healthdsgn)
anova(race_sex_glm)

# This has one independent polytomous variable
# Does not output a normal ANOVA table. Returns NULL
race_glm = svyglm(BMI~RACE, healthdsgn)
anova(race_glm)
```

This problem doesn't occur when I use the `aov` function in R — both of these produce normal ANOVA output:

```
summary(aov(BMI~RACE+SEX, healthsvy))
summary(aov(BMI~RACE, healthsvy))
```

However, `aov` doesn't account for survey weights so the output would be incorrect.

What should I do to resolve this?

Comment: The documentation says `aov()` function can take `weights` as its argument.

Comment: @yh6 Thanks, that worked for me. Do you know why that issue is there with only one independent variable using `anova()` though?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not familiar with `survey` package, but as I tried it, I'm not quite sure but it seems that the output of `anova(svyglm(svydesign()))` is likelihood ratio test result instead of ANOVA result.